# Use of undeclared identifier "applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation" in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode

I updated my Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 and now i ran into these issues.
Previously the code worked fine with Xcode 5

I have this code in red
- (void)applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification;
in my AppDelegate.m

with error 
"Use of undeclared identifier "applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation"

and also

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo

with error
"Invalid argument type "void" to unary expression"

Here's the screenshot
http://prntscr.com/4liq0n
[Error][1]
Also having another parse issue
http://prntscr.com/4liqcl

Can somebody please help me out?
thanks!

Comment: Start by getting rid of the semicolon at the end of `:(NSNotification *)notification;` and see how much that fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Philip Mills is right, the semicolon is your error here.